# Is 'difference of two squares' in this limit proof acceptable?

Tags: limits

$k,a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq b$

You know:  $a^k-b^k = (a^{k/2} + b^{k/2}) \cdot (a^{k/2} - b^{k/2})$

So if we keep the rule for the second part (factor with difference): $a^k-b^k = (a^{k/2} + b^{k/2}) \cdot (a^{k/4} + b^{k/4}) \cdot (a^{k/8} + b^{k/8}) \dots (a^{k/2n} + b^{k/2n}) \cdot (a^{k/2n} - b^{k/2n})$

And if we keep going like this forever, it becomes: 
$a^k-b^k = (a^{k/2} + b^{k/2}) \cdot (a^{k/4} + b^{k/4}) \cdot (a^{k/8} + b^{k/8}) \dots (a^{k/\infty} + b^{k/\infty}) \cdot(a^{k/\infty} - b^{k/\infty})$

So if we apply limit rules here (which is ${number \over \infty} = 0$): $a^k-b^k = (a^{k/2} + b^{k/2}) \cdot (a^{k/4} + b^{k/4}) \cdot(a^{k/8} + b^{k/8}) \dots (a^{0} + b^{0}) \cdot (a^{0} - b^{0})$

$a^k-b^k = (a^{k/2} + b^{k/2}) \cdot (a^{k/4} + b^{k/4}) \cdot (a^{k/8} + b^{k/8}) \dots (1 + 1) \cdot (1 - 1)$

$a^k-b^k = (a^{k/2} + b^{k/2}) \cdot (a^{k/4} + b^{k/4}) \cdot (a^{k/8} + b^{k/8}) \dots (2) \cdot (0)$

$a^k-b^k = 0$

As $\ \ a \neq b$, value of $\ a^k - b^k \ $ can't be $0$. However it is, according to the rules of limit. So I think those limit rules are just acceptances.

*Sorry for bad English*

Comment: I'm afraid you can't plug in the "last element" of an infinite sequence like that. The moment you started talking about $a^{k/\infty}$ your proof was invalid.

Comment: Manipulating the symbol $\infty$ rarely works well. For example, we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n+1}{n} = 2$, but suppose we think playing with $\infty$ is a good idea. We might be tempted to think that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n+1}{n} = \frac{2\infty + 1}{\infty},$$ which is "obviously" $\frac{\infty}{\infty} = 1$, since "obviously" $2\infty + 1 = \infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a number of problems with your "rules of the limit". First of all you can't pretend that, that infinite product has a final term. It doesn't. Second you can't plug in for the limit at the end in the way you did since you are ignoring the infinitely many products in front.

**edit** response to the comment.

No you can't. The trouble IMO is you are really performing a different limit than you think you are. Or possibly two limits at once depending on how you look at it.

Let's take a look at why not. The limit you are really taking is the following $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a^{k/2^n}-b^{k/2^n})\prod_{i=1}^n (a^{k/2^i}+b^{k/2^i})$$
Your argument boils down to saying I will just take the limit of the first term and say that's $0$ so the whole limit is $0$. That's obviously not true in general. An easy way to see this is for example
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\prod_{i=1}^n i$$
The limit of the first term $\frac{1}{n}$ is $0$ but the limit of the whole formula is obviously infinity since really it's just a different way to write $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}n!=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-1)!$$

Comment: But all those numbers in front are just numbers and since any number multiplied by 0 is 0 so it is 0. However, you are right on the 'last term'. Since this is a rule in mathematics and not a function, there is no variable that goes to infinity, we apply the rule infinitly. I think it will be clear if we look only the last term of the equation. Let n be the number of times we apply the rule and k is the first power. So the last term will be: $(a^{k/2n} - b^{k/2n})$. As we keep applying the rule, n is increasing. I think at this point i can write it like $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a^{k/2n} - b^{k/2n})$

Comment: whic became an easy limit problem. It is 0.   Also because of my bad English, I think i couldn't express myself well. My point was; rules of limit were sensless to me since I learned them. Rules accept that if you divide somethin infinitly, it will become 0. And I tried to proove that is not a valid statement.